# Security essentials error code: 0x80501001

Tags: ms-security-essentials

Using Microsoft Security Essentials, I am getting an error code `0x80501001`. How do I get rid of it? What does the error actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google would have sufficed:

> The 0x80501001 error is a generic "failed to complete action"error. This will usually occur when the detected threat is in a zip file. If the detection was in a zip file there are a few options. You can uncheck "Scan archive files" or uncheck "Scan removable drives". While this may sound risky it is not really since malware can't do anything to harm your computer while it is zipped inside an archive. Another option is to delete the zip file if you really don't need it or if you do need it you can extract it to a folder, scan the folder, remove the detected malware, zip the cleaned folder and save it, then delete the originally infected zip file.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanning/error-code-0x80501001-while-cleaning-detected/cac6fe4d-8ac1-4ff2-a372-e05dfa0e5c15)

Comment: If I extract the zipped file, I will have problems.  In the past, when I got certain errors that arose because the zip is to large... is there a reg key or something that I could edit to increase the maximum size of the zipped file that Security Essentials would scan?